# How Square implemented data transfer to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, square

Some days ago I saw a interesting device for iphone, square, here: https://squareup.com/

you can plug it into iphone's earphone socket, and it can transfer data to iphone. A running App on iphone can receive it.

does any one know how it implemented? I guess it can encode data to audio stream and "sing" it, and App on phone can record the sound and decode it. but how to? is there a protocol or SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The implemention is likely to be no different to that of a simple [acoustic modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_coupler). The relevant APIs include [Audio Units](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (low-level) or [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (higher level).

Matt Gallagher has written an excellent (as always!) post on creating an [iOS tone generator](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html), which is one way of enabling what you are after.